# "No space left on device" when writing to NTFS on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, ubuntu-12.04, ntfs, inode

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and want to backup data to my external hard drive which is NTFS.

When running `cp -rp` or `rsync`, I get `no space left` errors like this:

```
`rsync: mkstemp "/media/Expansion Drive/.../home/username/filename" failed: No space left on device (28)`
```

But there is room

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdf1       1.9T  1.6T  314G  84% /media/Expansion Drive
```

And there are inodes:

```
# df -i
Filesystem        Inodes    IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdf1      343460980 14216701 329244279    5% /media/Expansion Drive
```

I tried running `rsync` as root, which doesn't fix the problem.

Is the disk really full? How should I fix this?

**Edit with additional data:**

Uses fuseblk, not sure how to check whether it uses ntsf-3g, but I guess it's standard in Ubuntu 12.04

```
$ mount
...
/dev/sdf1 on /media/Expansion Drive type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

`dmesg`shows no additional data or errors.

The files are not particularly big - especially not 300+ GB big.

Writing anything else fails as well:

```
$ echo "hello world" > /media/Expansion\ Drive/.../home/username/test.file
bash: /media/Expansion Drive/.../home/username/test.file: No space left on device
```

Comment: Are you using ntfs-3g? Have you done a check on the filesystem? Does `dmesg` have any errors in it? Are the files big? Is anything able to write to the file system? Can you consider something other than NTFS?

Comment: Is this specific to rsync and cp -rp? What happens if you just try cp with a single file?

Comment: Have added infos in post above. I'm currently checking the drive on a Win7 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `chkdsk /f` on the drive a Windows 7 machine resulted in some repairs. Now `rsync` runs without problems.

Comment: I have happily used as alternative - `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1` (with unmount before and mount after) as suggested at https://superuser.com/questions/853699/chkdsk-f-r-alternative-in-ubuntu-linux